# .htaccess redirect: convert path to GET variables?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Can a .htaccess guru show me an example of this?

This url:

```
http://www.api.com/user/1
```

Should be translated to:

```
http://www.api.com/endpoint/?entity=user&id=1
```

This url:

```
http://www.api.com/user/1/?action=help
```

Should be translated to:

```
http://www.api.com/endpoint/?entity=user&id=1&action=help
```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$ /endpoint/?entity=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Err, how to make `id` optional?